# Updating location after an interval of 10 mins using html, google Map API and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm writing a piece of code that will find the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE of the user and will save it do MySQL Database via PHP on button click. It give me the co ordinates on popup but is not saving it to database. Here' my code -

I believe my client side on edit.php is not correct.

```
<?php

include_once("php_includes/database.php");
 // If not logged in - Redirect to login
if( $log_user == ""){
header("location: index.php");
exit();
 }
    ?>

   <?php

         $sql     = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$log_user' LIMIT 1";
         $result  = $database->query($sql);
         while($record = $database->fetch_array($result)){
         $fn                    = $record['fname'];
         $ln                    = $record['lname'];
         $latlon                = $record['latlon'];
          }
        ?>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $fname                   = trim($database->escape_value(ucfirst(preg_replace('#                        [^a-zA-Z ]#i', '',$_POST['fname']))));
      $lname                   = trim($database->escape_value(ucfirst(preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z ]#i', '',$_POST['lname']))));
       $latlon                  = trim($database->escape_value(preg_replace('#[^a-z0- 9., ]#i', '', $_POST['latlon'])));



     $sql = "UPDATE users SET
            fname             = '{$fname}',
    lname             = '{$lname}',
    latlon            = '{$latlon}',
    WHERE user        = '{$log_user}'";



           $query = $database->query($sql);
          if($database->affected_rows() == 1){
          header("location: profile.php?u=$log_user");
            exit();
           }        

              }
              }
             ?>
         <?php
            if(isset($_POST["latlon"])){// Button which updates location VIA Google Map API
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
         include_once("php_includes/db_conn.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES

    $latlon = trim($database->escape_value(preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9.,]#i', '',  $_POST['latlon'])));

         // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
          if($latlon =="notSet"){
         echo "The form submission is missing values.";
            } else {
            // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
           // Begin UPDATING Location data into the database
           $sql    = "UPDATE users SET
                       latlon            = '{$latlon}',
               WHERE user        = '{$log_user}'";
               $query  = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
               echo "update_done";

                }

                   }
                 ?>



       <html>
            <head>
                  <title>Edit Profile</title>

                 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geo.js"> </script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/auto.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
         function locme(){
       if(latlon == "notSet"){
    status.innerHTML = "Please use locate button to verify your city.";
          }  else {
      _("upbtn").style.display = "none";
       status.innerHTML = 'updating...';
      var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "edit_profile.php");
               ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "update_done"){
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("upbtn").style.display = "block";
            } 
          }
        }
         ajax.send("&latlon="+latlon);
   }
      }
         </script>


  </head>

      <body>
         <?php include("nav_bar_1.php"); ?>

         <div class="page_index">
        <h2>Edit Your Profile</h2>
         <div id="status"></div>
         <div id="abcd"></div>


           <br/>
            <form id="edit_form"  action="edit_profile.php" method="post">


             <h4>Name</h4>
     <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($fn); ?>" >
     <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($ln); ?>" >
           <button class="upbtn" onClick="getLocation();locme();">Locate me now</button>    //Button which find LONG and LAT of user when user hits.
         </form>

             </div>
               <?php include_once("footer_bar_1.php"); ?>
           </body>
         </html>
```

And here's MAP API CODE

```
       var latlon = "notSet";
       function getLocation (){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPos, getError);
           }

         function getPos(position){
         latlon = position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
         alert(latlon);
           }

              function getError(error){
              var locError = error.code;
              var latlon   = "notSet";
              alert(latlon);
              }
```

Comment: Where does `$log_user` come from? It seems undefined. Do you perhaps mean to use a session variable instead?

Comment: Can you narrow down your problem a bit?  Have you done any debugging to determine where you script execution varies from what you expect? Are you getting any errors?